# Grep columns by values in different dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `df1`:

```
CHR   SNP          Pos  Ref Min
1   rs3094315   113934  A   G
1   rs12124819  126070  A   G
1   rs28765502  135853  C   T
1   rs9419478   158202  C   T
1   rs4881551   159076  G   A
```

and this `df2`:

```
CHR     SNP     A1  A2  MAF     NCHROBS
1   rs3094315   G   A   0.1402  214
1   rs12124819  G   A   0.1887  212
1   rs28765502  C   T   0.3113  212
1   rs7419119   G   T   0.2243  214
1   rs950122    C   G   0.1944  216
```

The first three rows have the same SNP names, so what I want to do is something like merge `d2` with `df1` based on coincidence in "SNP" and if they match evaluate if "A1" in `df2` and "Ref" in `df1` are the same, if not just Change the position letters and then subtract `1-MAF` value as this at the end:

```
CHR     SNP     A1  A2  MAF     NCHROBS
1   rs3094315   A   G   0.8598  214
1   rs12124819  A   G   0.8113  212
1   rs28765502  C   T   0.3113  212
1   rs7419119   G   T   0.2243  214
1   rs950122    C   G   0.1944  216
```

What I tried is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd
df3=pd.merge(df2,df1, on=['SNP'])
df3['subtract']=np.where(df3['A1']!=df3['Ref']###print the subtract result 1-MAF= in 'subtract col')
```

But I don't want to lose those values that don't match in merge and print the subtract result of `1-MAF`'s value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first right `merge` on "SNP", then use `np.where` to evaluate the condition. Then fill NaN values with the corresponding values. Finally drop the columns with missing values and rearrange to fit the desired outcome:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='SNP', how='right', suffixes=('_',''))
merged_df['MAF'] = np.where(merged_df['Ref'].eq(merged_df['A2']), 1-merged_df['MAF'], merged_df['MAF'])
merged_df['Ref'] = merged_df['Ref'].fillna(merged_df['A1'])
merged_df['Min'] = merged_df['Min'].fillna(merged_df['A2'])
merged_df = merged_df.dropna(axis=1).drop(columns=['A2','A1']).rename(columns={'Ref':'A1', 'Min':'A2'})[['CHR','SNP','A1','A2','MAF','NCHROBS']]
```

Output:

```
   CHR         SNP A1 A2     MAF  NCHROBS
0    1   rs3094315  A  G  0.8598      214
1    1  rs12124819  A  G  0.8113      212
2    1  rs28765502  C  T  0.3113      212
3    1   rs7419119  G  T  0.2243      214
4    1    rs950122  C  G  0.1944      216
```

Comment: I tried use that last line but it said KeyError: "['MAF'] not in index". When I used merged_df = merged_df.dropna(axis=1) 'MAF' column is not there

Comment: @HctorAlessandroLpezHernndez then probably there are missing values in "MAF" in `df2`. Since you're doing operations on that particular column, maybe drop the rows with missing values (or fill them with something else) first and then merge.